# AirPlay doesn't appear in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, airplay

**SOLVED**
With iOS 10.2 AirPlay button has reappeared and it still works. Apple poltergeist!

In iOS 9 I used this code to detect Airplay devices. With deployment target 10.00 it doesn't appear. In Control Center I can find my airplay devices, but in my app the uiview doesn't show anything.
In my capabilities I have checked under "background mode", Audio, AirPlay and picture in picture. Maybe I forget some new setting of this blessed sandbox?
Thanks for your patience

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *airplay;

MPVolumeView *myVolumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: airplay.bounds];
[myVolumeView setShowsVolumeSlider:NO];
[myVolumeView setShowsRouteButton:YES];
myVolumeView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.3,0.3);
[myVolumeView setRouteButtonImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myIconAirPlay"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[airplay addSubview: myVolumeView];
```

Answer (score 0):

From apple doc :

> If there is an Apple TV or other AirPlay-enabled device in range, the route button allows the user to choose it. If there is only one audio output route available, the route button is not displayed.
>   https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpvolumeview

Have you checked if `var areWirelessRoutesAvailable: Bool { get }` returns true or false on the `MPVolumeView` ?

I thinks it's the reason why your button is no longer appearing, It wouldn't be new if iOS10 update broke some Airplay devices until they have been updated too.

Comment: It is only for audio output. In Spotify, for example, I can show, in app, AirPlay audio devices. How can I get the same?